# User Authorization with Facebook

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, facebook, authorization

I have implemented Facebook user authentication with my current project and now I would like to implement authorization. I need authorization to check if a user is logged in when they try to perform an action. Can anyone point me to a resource that is relevant to my situation or perhaps help me out?

Edit: I believe this authorization needs to be server-side, because I also want to verify specific user permissions (such as if the user is an administrator).

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class User : Entity
{

    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long FacebookID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long Expires { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

you can do this with Javascript SDK

```
$('button.action').click(function() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if(response.session) {
        // user logged in.
      } else {
          // log him in.
      }
    });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I want to authorize actions that a logged in user takes. Since this information is client side, don't I need to do authorization server side? Since I do not implement standard username/password login and simply use facebook login, in order to authorize shouldn't I compare the access token in the cookie from facebook to the access token I store in the database to make sure the user is the correct user and not, for example, attempting to impersonate someone with higher permissions?

Comment: if it's on your site an access token can expire even if the user is logged in

Comment: Handling expired access tokens has nothing to do with my current issue. I want to make sure that a user has certain permissions, like being an admin, in order to perform a certain action. Since these permissions are stored in the database, I must check against the database.